# Converting a member function to a static function in C++

Tags: c++

I am writing a memory testing framework, in which I replace dynamic memory allocation functions with my own (eg. malloc, realloc, free, etc.). However, the system expects static functions (I can not change this).

I have a MemoryTester class, which logs the memory calls, and I want to bind its member function implementations of the memory allocation functions. Is this possible with C++?

EDIT:

Here is some code highlighting what I'm trying to do:

```
typedef void*(allocateFuncPtr) (uint8_t);
typedef void (freeFuncPtr) (void*);

void setAllocateFunction(allocateFuncPtr) {...}
void setFreeFunction(freeFuncPtr) {...}


class MemoryTester
{
    void *malloc(uint8_t size);
    void free(void *ptr);
}

int main()
{
    MemoryTester *tester = new MemoryTester();

    //want to set allocate and free functions to those in tester
    setAllocateFunction( tester->getAllocateFunction() );
    setFreeFunction( tester->getFreeFunction() );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific object to call these member functions on at binding time?

Comment: I can't see your currend code, do you need function pointers? if not take a look at std::bind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After the edit, the intent seems clearer to me. The simplest thing that you can do is using static member functions in the `MemoryTester` instead of non-static member functions. If they need to hold state, that state will have to be moved to be `static` members of the class.

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, but I was wondering if there was a better way. I guess C++ isn't flexible in this way.

Comment: This is unrelated to flexibility, a non-static member function has a hidden `this` parameter, and that makes the signatures incompatible. If you were allowed to just pass the pointer to the member function, whose state would it be modifying, what object would be pointed by the implicit `this` argument?

Comment: In other languages (JavaScript for example), you can dynamically create a function at run time, so you can create a new set of functions for each object you initialize. In other languages, still, you can curry the object pointer into the function. I was just wondering if C++ has something similar.

Comment: The problem is that you have created a fixed interface, if instead of *requiring* argument-less functions in the interface you used a more generic option you could add the object to the call. For example, if the setAllocator function stored a `std::function<void* (int)>`, and the function itself was a template: `template <typename F> void setAllocator( F allocator );` (or also use `std::function` there), then you could use `std::bind` to add the object to the call: `setAllocator( &MemoryTester::allocate, &tester ) );`.

Comment: I am not suggesting that change in the interface, as that would incur in a dynamic dispatch for each call to the allocator, and if you don't really need it in production, it does not make sense to modify the design for the test. The issue here is that in C++ you have to compromise, but you can actually decide the compromises.

Comment: Ahm... still C++ is not as flexible as Javascript (you cannot create functions at runtime, only at compile time), but for most of the issues it is more than enough --it is much more flexible than other compiled languages, and less so that fully dynamic languages.

Answer (score 3):

If your compiler supports 0x lambdas, you can use a closure:

```
int main() {
  MemoryTester tester;  // If no need for dynamic allocation, don't use it.

  setAllocateFunction([&tester](uint8_t size) { return tester.malloc(size); });
  setFreeFunction([&tester](void *p) { tester.free(p); });

  return 0;
}
```

No changes required to your MemoryTester class nor whichever library setAllocateFunction & setFreeFunction belong to.

---

Without lambdas, instead of [a singleton class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023001/converting-a-member-function-to-a-static-function-in-c/6023460#6023460), use a single global object:

```
struct MemoryTester {
  void* malloc(uint8_t size);  // Neither are static.
  void free(void *p);
};

MemoryTester tester_a;
void* tester_a_malloc(uint8_t size) { return tester_a.malloc(size); }
void tester_a_free(void *p) { return tester_a.free(p); }

int main() {
  setAllocateFunction(&tester_a_malloc);
  setFreeFunction(&tester_a_free);
}
```

The advantage here is the **entire MemoryTester class isn't hamstrung because of one particular need** for it.  You can create more functions (e.g. tester_b_malloc/free) as needed to accommodate other uses within the same program.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using GCC, then you can have the linker wrap the function for you with the --wrap option ( or -Wl,--wrap,malloc ).

Then you can intercept calls to malloc because all calls to that function will be redirected to __wrap_malloc.  You can call the real (original c-lib) malloc function using the name __real_malloc or you can substitute a replacement of your own (and if __real_malloc isn't called, then the linker may be able to dead-strip out the original c-lib malloc all-together).

```
void *__wrap_malloc (size_t c)
{
  printf ("malloc called with %zu\n", c);
  return __real_malloc (c);
}
```

FWIW, you can replace the global new and delete operations and then you can have a program using only your own memory system (even when you use code from 3rd party compiled libraries as long as they haven't overloaded global new and delete).

Here's some great info: [Tutorial of Replacing "new" and "delete"](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill15.htm)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, because they're not member functions.

Comment: The question is quite unclear because he says he wants to override the memory functions (malloc, et al).  You're saying he wants to do it with member functions.  I'm not quite sure where he claims these functions must be "static" works out then because his member functions aren't defined as "static".  Anyhow... guess it's just poor wording choice where none of the answers are going to be correct because the question is ill defined.

Comment: He said in his question that he can;t change that his system takes free function pointers. The question is well-defined- he has a framework that wants free function pointers and he wants to use a member function

Comment: No, he actually says and I quote "the system expects static functions".  However, his example uses member functions, which are neither static functions nor static member functions.

Comment: I answered how to replace items when "the system expects static functions".  Replacing member functions has to be done with virtuals or through a pointer indirection (pointer held by the class passed into the memory tester).  The only choice would be static memeber variables holding redirection pointers if he wants them to be static member functions.  But, it's quite unclear which of these he wants.  There are a couple thousand C++ experts here and his question would be simple if well defined so I'd expect someone to answer it correctly if it wasn't so unclear.

Comment: Sorry if the question wasn't clear. I was asking that given the interface above (which I can't change) for plugging in my own memory functions, can I use member functions to interface with it. I currently use static methods, but I was wondering if I could do what I wanted in an object-oriented manner.

Comment: Regardless of using static functions, You could simply call malloc and free from your C++ interface class's member functions, and using GCC wrapping capability, redirect your calls.  It's a compiler specific solution (which I specified from the beginning) but it would still work just fine for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you ask, there is no "binding" to do. Once the memory have been allocated, you can tell the compiler it's type by user a cast, in your case a reinterpret_cast. For example, in you allocation function:

```
unsigned char* raw_memory = allocation( std::size_t );
MyFinalType* object = reinterpret_cast<MyFinalType*>(raw_memory); // tells the compiler to take this memory as a MyFinalType.
```

Then you return your final type.

To know wich type to use, you'll certainly want to use templates.

Don't forget that C++ is a statically typed language: you can't bind functions to an object type. Ok you can, but the, you have to use std::function or function pointers, that are not what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

Not unless you make a global object. If the framework takes regular function pointers, then you're stuck with what it provides, and if it doesn't provide for the traditional void* userdata style, then you're stuffed, or it's global object time.

Answer (score -2):

Have one singleton MemoryTester object, and have bridge static functions that call member functions of that object.

Comment: I'm downvoting this. The OP might appreciate the use of a global object, but I see absolutely no need to enforce that object to be unique.

Comment: [Don't use singletons](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/)

Comment: Now that I know that singleton is forbidden word for all possible scenarios I wish I had incorporated a goto in answer as well.

Comment: There are scenarios where a goto is acceptable (Generated code comes to mind as one that most people can agree on). I can't say the same about a singleton. So yeah, perhaps you should have incorporated a goto